# Why I'm getting null on the variable target?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class IKControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InteractableItem[] lookObj = null;
    public GameObject objToThrow;
    public Text text;
    public Text textMultiLine;
    public float weightDamping = 1.5f;
    public float maxDistance = 10f;
    public bool RightHandToTarget = true;
    public float throwSpeed;

    private List<InteractableItem> allDetectedItems;
    private Animator animator;
    private InteractableItem lastPrimaryTarget;
    private Quaternion savedRotation;
    private float lerpEndDistance = 0.1f;
    private float finalLookWeight = 0;
    private bool transitionToNextTarget = false;
    private InteractableItem target;
    private bool throwObj = false;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        allDetectedItems = new List<InteractableItem>();
    }

    // Callback for calculating IK
    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {
        if (lookObj != null)
        {
            InteractableItem primaryTarget = null;
            float closestLookWeight = 0;

            // Here we find the target which is closest (by angle) to the players view line
            allDetectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (InteractableItem target in lookObj)
            {
                Vector3 lookAt = target.transform.position - transform.position;
                lookAt.y = 0f;

                // Filter out all objects that are too far away
                //if (lookAt.magnitude > maxDistance) continue;
                if (lookAt.magnitude > target.distance) continue;

                float dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(new Vector3(transform.forward.x, 0f, transform.forward.z).normalized, lookAt.normalized);
                float lookWeight = Mathf.Clamp(dotProduct, 0f, 1f);
                if (lookWeight > 0.1f && lookWeight > closestLookWeight)
                {
                    closestLookWeight = lookWeight;
                    primaryTarget = target;
                    allDetectedItems.Add(target);
                }
            }

            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                if ((lastPrimaryTarget != null) && (lastPrimaryTarget != primaryTarget) && (finalLookWeight > 0f))
                {
                    // Here we start a new transition because the player looks already to a target but
                    // we have found another target the player should look at
                    transitionToNextTarget = true;
                }
            }

            // The player is in a neutral look position but has found a new target
            if ((primaryTarget != null) && !transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                lastPrimaryTarget = primaryTarget;
                //finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, closestLookWeight, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 1f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(primaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget && target.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = primaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 1f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, primaryTarget.transform.position);

                    // -> new code block
                    if (finalLookWeight > 0.95f) // here you can play with a value between 0.95f -> 1.0f
                    {
                        // call your funtion to shoot something here
                        throwObj = true;
                        target = primaryTarget;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Let the player smoothly look away from the last target to the neutral look position
            if ((primaryTarget == null && lastPrimaryTarget != null) || transitionToNextTarget)
            {
                finalLookWeight = Mathf.Lerp(finalLookWeight, 0f, Time.deltaTime * weightDamping);
                float bodyWeight = finalLookWeight * .75f;
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(finalLookWeight, bodyWeight, 1f);
                animator.SetLookAtPosition(lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);

                if (RightHandToTarget && target.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action)
                {
                    Vector3 relativePos = lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position - transform.position;
                    Quaternion rotationtoTarget = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rotationtoTarget);
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, finalLookWeight * 0.5f * closestLookWeight);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, lastPrimaryTarget.transform.position);
                }

                if (finalLookWeight < lerpEndDistance)
                {
                    transitionToNextTarget = false;
                    finalLookWeight = 0f;
                    lastPrimaryTarget = null;
                }
            }

            // Show primary object found by the player
            if (primaryTarget != null)
            {
                text.text = "Item found: " + primaryTarget.description;
            }
            else
            {
                text.text = "";
            }
        }
    }

    private void ThrowObject()
    {
        if (target.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action)
        {
            objToThrow.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objToThrow.transform.position, target.transform.position, throwSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (throwObj == true)
        {
            ThrowObject();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to debug using breakpoints and target is not null but when the player facing a target and interact with it then target become null on this line :

```
if (RightHandToTarget && target.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action)
```

And this script is attached to each target object :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InteractableItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum InteractableMode // your custom enumeration
    {
        Description,
        Action
    };

    public InteractableMode interactableMode = InteractableMode.Description;

    public float distance;

    private bool action = true;

    [TextArea(1, 10)]
    public string description = "";

    public void ActionOnItem()
    {
        if(interactableMode == InteractableMode.Action && distance <= 5f && action == true)
        {


            action = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure why target is null when interacting with a target object.

I found that if I remove or mark not to use on both places :

```
if (RightHandToTarget /*&& target.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action*/)
```

Then it's working fine without any null.
But when the line/s is :

```
if (RightHandToTarget && target.interactableMode == InteractableItem.InteractableMode.Action)
```

Then target will be null. and I want the hand to be raised only if the InteractableMode is Action.

Comment: The only place you set a target is within a condition where a target must exists. You might want to review the logic of your code here.

Comment: Found ho to do it. Thanks.

Comment: When you say "Found how to do it" does that mean you solved your problem? If so, please explain your solution in an Answer below. That can help future game devs who run into similar trouble.